# Add table record using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the HTML structure like like:

```
<button type="button">Add Column Record</button>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th> Header 1</th>

    <td> L1</td>
    <td> L1</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<th> Header 2</th>

    <td> L2 </td>
    <td> L2 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <th> Header 3</th>

    <td> L3</td>
    <td> L3</td>

</tr>
```

I want to add a vertical record to the rightest column after pressing a button. How should I implement this effect using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var table = $('table');
    var newCell = null;

    table.find('tr').each(function(index) {
        newCell = $('<td/>');
        newCell.text('L' + (index+1));
        $(this).append(newCell);
    });
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/8RmS8/

Answer (score 1):

check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/MMXnY/1/

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $('table tr').each(function(i, v){
     $(this).append($('td:last',this).clone().text('L'+parseInt(i+1)));
   });
});
```

You can iterate through each `tr` then `make a clone of the last td and then put text and increase the number by parsing it then append it after last td.`

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Each of the functions do a slightly different append.  Read them and find out what one you want to use.

Example:

BEFORE

```
<div class="area"></div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('<p>Test</p>').appendTo('.area');
```

AFTER

```
<div class="area"><p>Test</p></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add one column, you can iterate on each `tr` of your table and add a new `td`

Example:

```
$("#id_of_your_table > tbody > tr").each(function(index, trElement) {

    // Add a new TD at the end
    $(trElement).append($(document.createElement("td")));

});
```

**Note** : Don't forget to add a `tbody` in your `table` for a good behaviour (Some browser will add it by default if it's not present)

example:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            .....
```

Here is a complete example:

```
<button id="addColumn">Add new column</button>
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>col 1</td>
            <td>col 2</td>
            <td>col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> col 1</td>
            <td> col 2</td>
            <td> col 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>

    // When DOM is ready
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Listen on the click on the button
        $("#addColumn").on('click', function(mouseEvent) {

            // Iterate on all TR of the table
            $("#id_of_your_table > tbody > tr").each(function(index, trElement) {

                // Add a new TD at the end
                $(trElement).append($(document.createElement("td")));

            });
        });

    });

</script>
```